# Configure Amazon RDS mysql to store Chinese Characters

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

How to configure the Amazon RDS to store Chinese Characters in the right way? Currently the text all becomes '????'.

I already created new parameter group and set character set as utf8 and modify the instance. Below are the detail info:

```
mysql> show variables like '%char%';
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                     |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                      |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                      |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                      |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                    |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                      |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                      |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                      |
| character_sets_dir       | /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.5.27.R1/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+


+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After following @Peter Venderberghe's answer to configure RDS, I still can not let it store Chinese characters correctly.

Finally, I used mysql command line to connect to RDS (you can use mysql [workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/) or other client tool you like)

> mysql -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD -h HOSTNAMEORIP DATABASENAME

note:

1). **remember to add your [current ip](http://checkip.dyndns.com/) to security group inbound of RDS before connecting to RDS**

2). you can get related information(security groups, `USERNAME`...etc) on [RDS console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home) besides `PASSWORD`. `PASSWORD` should be the one you created for the instance. `HOSTNAMEORIP` is "Endpoint"(without the port) on the console.

3). there is no space between -p and PASSWORD. it's exactly `-pPASSWORD`.

After connecting to mysql with the tool you are comfortable with, you need to give it some commands:

```
# set character set and collation for database
mysql> alter database DATABASENAME CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
--------
# set character set and collation for new records in a table
mysql> ALTER TABLE TABLENAME CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
# set character set and collation for existing records in a table
mysql> ALTER TABLE TABLENAME CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

you may want to write a script to do this task if you have many tables. However, it's not in the scope of this answer.

After configuring as above, you should be able to rock with Chinese characters!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using RDS, you can set up Parameter Group for your mysql instance.

1. Create a new Parameter Group
2. Modify your db instance with new parameter group
3. reboot your db instance

Done! It should be quite straightforward. You'll see when you get there.

Comment: This is by far the easiest way to do this. And in my opinion the correct way as well.

Comment: I confirm that this method is the easiest. The OP didn't give details. What I changed was "character_set_*" and "collation_*". there are about 8 settings, I changed all of them to "utf8" and "utf8_unicode_ci"

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are using UTF-8 character set.

The easiest way to set the charsets permanently is to update your client my.cnf with the following:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

Detailed information about the connection charset you can find here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-connection.html

When using the MySQL API functions ( PHP client e.g. ) you can set the connection charset by sending the query

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

You can configure Amazon RDS to use Utf-8 character set by following this blog:
http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/howto-configure-an-amazon-rds-instance-to-use-utf-8-925.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please see my update. Still didn't get it work after using utf8. should something be missed ...

Comment: How you are viewing stored data? By using GUI tool or by using a browser? 
Before entering data make sure that you are executing "Set names UTF8;" also you can refer this post as well http://mandarin.about.com/od/characters/ss/display_chars.htm